# Problem with sendmail(email, send_to_email, msg.as_string())

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to attach and send multiple attachments to list of emails individually

```
import smtplib
import openpyxl
import os.path
from email import encoders
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

email_source_workbook = load_workbook(filename=r'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\final mailer\mail list.xlsx')
curr_sheet = email_source_workbook['ml']
attachment_location = [r'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\final mailer\at1.txt']
row_len = curr_sheet.max_row
email = 'example@email.com'
password = 'pswrd'



subject = 'test subj'       #Subject

message = '''this 
is test 
mail
ok?
''' 

msg = MIMEMultipart()



with smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587) as svr:

    print("Initializing the server")
    svr.ehlo()
    svr.starttls()
    svr.ehlo()
    svr.login(email, password)
    print("login sucessful")


    for curr_attachment in attachment_location:
        name_of_attachment = os.path.basename(curr_attachment)
        attachment_payload = MIMEBase('application' , "octet-stream")
        attachment_payload.set_payload(open(curr_attachment, "rb").read())
        encoders.encode_base64(attachment_payload)
        attachment_payload.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment' , filename=name_of_attachment) 

    for i in range(1 , row_len+1):
        print("###################")
        send_to_email = curr_sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1).value
        msg['From'] = email
        msg['To'] = send_to_email
        msg['Subject'] = subject

        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
        svr.sendmail(email, send_to_email, msg.as_string())

    svr.quit()
```

i can send the mail but the problem is for example there are 3 email addresses in the excel file 
it will send the first mail to the first recipient 
perfectly fine 
then in the second mail it'll send it to the second and first recipient with the attachment + the wole body of mail as one more attachment 
and to the third it will send to the first two recipients with the third with the original attachment with two same attachments that are the body of the mail. it will go on so fourth with n number of email addresses. i.e. 10 mail id and on the 10th mail the 10th recipient with all the previous 9 and 10 attachments.

Answer (score 1):

found the solution

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
```

should be in

```
for i in range(1 , row_len+1):
        print("###################")
        send_to_email = curr_sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1).value
        msg['From'] = email
        msg['To'] = send_to_email
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg = MIMEMultipart() 
        msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
        svr.sendmail(email, send_to_email, msg.as_string())
```